# Similar download manager in Chrome to that in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

In Firefox, I am using a download manager which can resume downloading if it breaks because of bad connection, and can automatically download multiple selected links in a webpage.

I tried some extensions in Chrome, but none has the above abilities.

I wonder what chrome extensions can do the above two?

[image]